# How can I access a language code for Urdu?

Tags: stanford-nlp, urdu

I am retraining a POS tag model of STANZA library. After updating the CONLLU files (dev,test, train), when I try to prepare the script by

```
python3 -m stanza.utils.datasets.prepare_pos_treebank UD_URDU-UDTB
```

It gives the following error

```
raise ValueError("Unable to find language code for %s" % lang)
ValueError: Unable to find language code for URDU
```

How can I fix it

Answer (score 1):

It expects capitalization to be standard.  Perhaps that is something we can update.  Try `UD_Urdu-UDTB`